# google Safe Search web filtering

Tags: search, google, images

I had an issue raised that a student did a google images search on Reece Bennett and on the second page, after removing safe search from moderate to off, they got some inappropriate images.
Blocking the preferences page wont help because there is a dropdown box to turn safe search off.
Is there a way to prevent users from changing the safe search options?
Has anyone sovled this problem before?

Comment: Just did that Google search myself, to see what was on it. Looks like they got a bit of a biology lesson! Mind you, my Mum busted her Grade 3 kids bringing in a CD of porn to look on the school computers at lunchtime. Grade 3! I bet they don't even know what those different bits are for.

Comment: Didn't know what the bits were for? How old were you when you learned how to use I/O ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some proxy filters, especially aimed for schools, have filtering that will automatically enable safe search from Google. I believe the filter we used from Microsoft had this feature, and I'm fairly sure that the big vendors for proxies and filtering have that feature built in.

Comment: We use fortinet products and I just found that it has the option but I cant get it to work...am working on it.